# How to run a previously built Canvas API project in simulator/smart-display?

Tags: html5-canvas, actions-on-google

I am trying to clone an application, which is given in their document under canvas API section. They have given an option for sample walkthrough [https://developers.google.com/actions/interactivecanvas/sample-walkthrough]. I have followed every step but I am getting an error that my intents are not handled. 
You can see the code at [github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-snowman-nodejs.git].

I have tried seeing all the intent handlers, Also, i have tried changing all the packages to the lastest one, as i have mentioned in the question.

I am using following packages:

```
{
  "name": "snowman-canvas-sample-functions",
  "description": "Snowman Actions on Google Interactive Canvas Sample Functions",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "preview",
    "firebase-admin": "~5.13.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.0.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint --fix \"**/*.js\"",
    "start": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "test": "npm run lint"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^6.0.1",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.13.0"
  }
}
```

i am getting "Dialogflow IntentHandler not found for intent: Welcome at Function" error in the welcome intent itself. Please assist me what should i try next.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your Dialogflow intent name and your Firebase Function intent handler name are the same.

[image]

From here, you'd need to implement a handler:

```
const { dialogflow } = require('actions-on-google')
const app = dialogflow()

app.intent('Welcome', conv => {
  conv.ask('Welcome!')
})
```

Comment: Hi Nick, you are right, the error can be resolved by this, but i have checked, all of my intents name matched and the function handler name are same. I think the problem is my dialogflow is not able to connect to my webhook. Do have any solution to fix this?

Comment: Error: Dialogflow IntentHandler not found for intent: Welcome at Function, this is the error i am getting

Comment: So you have your Dialogflow intent named "Welcome at Function" and your webhook has `app.intent('Welcome at Function', conv => ...`?